# Is time unbounded in the future direction?

Tags: cosmology, time, universe, space-expansion, singularities

Time likely had a beginning, because of the big bang theory. But will time ever end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The universe appears to have a lower bound in the time dimension, why not an upper bound?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130685/)

Comment: @JohnRennie I apologize. I did not know if this question had been asked before.