# Cyclic/Orbiting/Oscillating Universe

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang

Edit: I've changed the title a couple times.

I hope this is not an exact duplicate of Big Bounce type questions.

Imagine two bodies in a very highly eccentric orbit around each other in their outward leg. When very far apart they seem to be moving directly away from each other, and when they reach their largest distance from each other and turn around, they seem to be headed right at each other, on a collision course. But they won't collide, they will miss each other. Now add bodies to this scenario in such a way that all their periods are the same, their orbital planes are randomly oriented, the orbits are very highly eccentric, and that they are all at their perihelion at the same time. I assume this situation can and will continue in what might be called oscillation - just an assumption.

My question is: Can the Universe be in this type of motion?

Whether or not it gets started with a big bang, could it then be cyclical, by virtue of the fact that all (or most) of the incoming matter will simply miss each other? This also assumes of course that inflation will reverse itself (bonus: has inflation reversal been ruled out?)

I know any obvious rotation of the Universe has been ruled out, but this seems distinct because there is no overall single orbital plane; not to mention that the very high eccentricity would be difficult to distinguish from pure expansion.

Comment: First, is it possible? If so, has it been ruled out as a possible alternative to a big crunch?

Comment: Said another way: If it turns out that inflation stops and everything in the universe starts to fall back into itself, what evidence is there that everything will fall to the exact same place at exactly the same time?

Comment: This seems to be the same as asking if the universe started from a point. For that see questions such as [What has been proved about the big bang, and what has not?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11136) and [What's the evidence supporting 1 singular Big Bang?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32598) Also of interest : [Is there a consensus on the fate of our universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25806)

Comment: The discussion regarding the fate of the universe comes close, but offers only a big crunch as a possibility. Why should there be a big crunch instead of a near miss, where everything just gets flung out again? If there is exactly zero net angular momentum, AND zero local angular momentum, I can see the inevitability of a big crunch. I don't know if the former has been ruled out, but the latter is manifestly false.